# What is the delta t on the conditional probability of failure (TTF)

Tags: probability-distributions

Can someone explain me what is the $\Delta$t of the conditional probability of failure (CPF) on hazard function? CPF = P { t $\le$ T $\le$ t+$\Delta t$} $\mid$ T > t}

$$CPF = \frac{R(t) - R(t- \Delta t )}{R(t)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Delta t$ is just "some (positive) increment on $t$".   This is *usually* a small increment.

$\mathsf P(t\leq T\leq t+\Delta t\mid T> t)$ is the probability that $T$ lies in some constant (positive) interval $\Delta t$ following $t$ given that $T$ is greater than $t$.

It's a convenient standard to understand $\Delta$*variable* to mean an increment of the variable; rather than introducing a new constant and needing to explaining what that is each and every time.   Though this notation *should* be explained at least *once* somewhere in the text, it is so standard some lazy authors may take it for granted that the reader will already understand.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.